# Angular reload page when new version is deployed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, reload

I have a SPA written in angular js. The problem now is that when I deploy a new version clients that already have the page open in the browser doesn't get the new version until they reload the browser.

What I'm looking for is a way for the angular app to see that new files exist on disk and reload the page. Or show the user a toast that reload is needed.

What is the best practice for this?

Also, this is not a cache issue. I have a build tool that names all files with a hash. Like app-32ab432bb.js etc.

Comment: use browser sync module to do this npm install -g browser-sync https://www.browsersync.io/

Comment: I really wouldn't say BrowserSync is a production ready update tool

Comment: This question is most likely too broad to answer directly but you could have a periodic check for a *version* file / resource. If the returned version is incremented from the last know one, show a message / reload the page via `$window.location.reload()`

Comment: Thanks Phil. Unless a better approach comes up I will do something like that.